# Is there a way in which I could get a function as a input ex.:(x^5+x^2+4) and then use the x as a variable in c++?

Tags: function, math, visual-c++

I am trying to make a algorithm in which I need the user to input a function but I do not know how I could use the x from the input as a variable and then do calculations using the function. How could I do that?

Comment: no. you need a tokenizer and a parser/evaluator to do that

Comment: You need what's called a parser to read a string and produce an internal representation of the expression, and then something to evaluate that representation. Take a look at Ginac (https://www.ginac.de/).

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use a function with arguments that are coefficients in a linear function. And the user input can be parsed to get the coeficients.